# 3D interpolation in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, 3d, interpolation, spline, surface

I am doing a project where I want to measure the surface topology of a telescope mirror. Now I have a point cloud with xyz-values:

[image]

What I want to do is to interpolate the area in between the measured points (without the hole in the middle), something like a 3-dimensional spline. Can someone give me a hint how to start here? Every help is very much appreciated. I do not expect anyone to do my work here, I just want to get some input.

Code language is VB.net

Thank you!

Comment: is this the type of thing you're meaning?https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/411341/how-to-calculate-surface-area-of-a-curved-plane

Comment: Sorry if I was not precisely enough. I dont need to calulate the area of a curved plane. I want to interpolate a circular surface with a hole by given data points. Thanks for you comment

Comment: Are the data points scattered and unorganized?  Can your surface be represented as function of (x, y) such as z=f(x,y)?

Comment: They are scattered and unorganized, so they cannot be represented as a function yet. I thought that I can Interpolate the point cloud as it is. Bad idea?